# How do I change the user agent of a device in Kaiosrt or WebIDE?

Tags: firefox, adb, settings, web-ide, kaios

I can see the following fields in “Device Preferences”.

[image: Device Preferences]

However, none of these preferences seem to control `navigator.userAgent`. I also tried looking into “Device Settings” but that doesn't have any field related to the user agent at all.

[image: Device Settings]

For reference, here is my runtime info.

[image: Runtime Info]

As you can see, the user agent is `Mozilla 5.0 (Mobile; rv:48.0) Gecko/48.0 Firefox/48.0`. I want to change the user agent to `Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; LYF/LF-2403/LYF-LF2403-000-01-3D-191217-i;Android; rv:48.0) Gecko/48.0 Firefox/48.0 KAIOS/2.0` to match the device user agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to treat it like a firefox browser:

1. Open "Device Preferences" and add a new string config with key `general.useragent.override` and value as whatever you need.
2. Restart your app in the simulator.

The overriden user agent in step 1 should start reflecting.